# Testing Jetpack Compose SwipeRight() - Back Navigation

Tags: testing, jetpack-compose, ui

Estoy realizado pruebas de UI para una app de Jetpack Compose.
Mi pregunta es, utilizando el gesto SwipeRight() se puede navegar hacía la pantalla previa?
Ya lo eh intentado pero no me lo ha permitido aún, no sé si sea posible o solo aplica este gesto (en testing) para simular animaciones en elementos individuales.

En caso de que sea posible, cómo debería de aplicarse.
O en su defecto, alguna manera de 'simular' la navegación a la pantalla previa, cuando no hay un botón como tal.

Gracias.